# How to generate a shared library using ndk for x-86 platform in android for some linux package

Tags: android-ndk, shared-libraries, x86-64, android-x86

I have an external linux source package and I have the full-setup of android JB code base.
I put the linux source package in external folder.The source package also contains Android.mk file through which I generate a shared library, lets say libabc.so using the mmm module build command.But all this is for arm-architecture.
I want the shared library for x86-64 architecture so that my application can run on x86-64 platform devices.
Can someone give me any idea on how shall I proceed to achieve my task.I want the libabc.so library for x86-64 platforms.